# Оформление цитаты-афоризма

Tags: цитата

...афоризм В. С. Черномырдина «Хотели как лучше, а получилось как всегда».
Правильно ли начинать афоризм с большой буквы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта фраза общеизвестная, ее часто цитируют, **причем в различных вариантах.**

А какие варианты существуют **по правилам**, попробуем перечислить.

1) **Оформление полной цитаты в виде прямой речи** (кавычки, двоеточие, прописная буква).

Мы часто думаем одно, а говорим другое. В этой связи вспоминается знаменитая фраза: **" Хотели как лучше, а получилось как всегда".**  [«Дело» (Самара), 2002.05.03].

2) **Цитата как член предложения** (кавычки сохраняются, двоеточия нет, фраза может быть неполной,  буква строчная или прописная)

Мне кажется, что ЕГЭ ― из серии **«хотели как лучше…» .**

И всё вышло не по российской традиции ― **«Хотели как лучше, а получилось как всегда»,** а прямо по Тициану: « нужный цвет в нужное место».

3) **Цитата используется как устойчивое выражение** (кавычек нет, фраза может быть неполной, но она вполне узнаваема)

Я не виню авторов ― они **хотели как лучше**.

Вот так. **Хотели — как лучше, а получилось — как всегда**.

**Хотели, как лучше…**

Да, я знаю, вы **хотели как лучше**.